# Qt5.5 qmake don't generate proper .pro file

Tags: qmake, qt5.5

Currently, I'm using Qt5.5 with Visual Studio 2015. 
After making UI files, I want to make a .pro file using the command **"qmake -project**" (VS2015 environment is set). And the .pro file is generated. 
After that I pass **"qmake -tp vc qtexample.pro "** to create visual studio project. The project is created without problem.

When I'm trying to build the project, it shows me a lot of linking errors. After googling the problem, I found a solution - to add this line **"QT += core gui widgets"**  in the .pro file.

So, my question is: Why didn't qmake write that line in the .pro file? What's wrong here? Should I always add manually this line in the .pro file? Is there any way to avoid manually adding the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core` and `gui` are added by default, however, `widgets` is not. This info is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Yup, I saw that by the time. Anyway, thanks for the answer :)